# Sharepoint 2007 Standard: Target Audience to AD group

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a web part that I am trying to conceal using target audience. Since I cannot see the AD users or groups in target audience, I tried creating a new Sharepoint Group which contained the AD group and added that, but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target directly to AD "security" group or distribution list.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/target-content-to-specific-audiences-HA010169053.aspx

```
To identify a target audience, you can use one or more of the following:

SharePoint groups
Distribution lists
Security groups
Global audiences
```

Regarding the workaround you have tried, its not supported. See
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948681

Can you explain the problem you are facing originally ? Can you try targeting directly to AD group.

Comment: Distribution lists and Security groups is empty. Global Audience just displays "All site users".

Comment: Do you have connections to AD set up ?

Comment: The link says that if I apply the hotfix it should work, but am I supposed to see the list of users and groups from the Active Directory in the Target Audience?  Well, I can see all AD users in Permissions. Where can I verify if the AD to Sharepoint is setup correctly?

Comment: AD users are queried directly by sharepoint. You need AD connection to import AD groups and other objects in order for audience targeting to work. See here http://vspug.com/ajaybawa/2006/09/25/moss-2007-user-and-profiles-import-from-active-directory/